# Why gcc 4.1 + gcov reports 100% branch coverage and newer (4.4, 4.6, 4.8) reports 50% for "p = new class;" line?

Tags: gcc, g++, branch, code-coverage, gcov

When gcc 4.1 (using gcov) next line:

`p = new Class;`

is reported as 100% branch coverage <-- THIS IS OK for me.

Why using gcc 4.4 and higher same line is reportted as:

`[+ -] p = new Class; (50% branch coverage)`... <-- THIS IS a problem for covering 100% !!!

Can I set any extra options to newer gcc versions in order to report the same branch coverage as gcc 4.1 for single lines as `p = new Class;`?

Answer (score 5):

Solved !

We have some C/C++ files with and without exceptions handling, so lcov/gcov process "exceptions handling" for each code block.

Inside a normal block, for example:

```
int main(void)
{
 ...
 ...
 [+ -] printf("Hello\n");
 ...
}
```

gcov reports that printf line has a "branch coverage" of 50% ---> WHY ?

Because exceptions handling is enabled !!!

In order to solve this issue, specify:

> -fno-exceptions

in g++ command line.

Example:

> g++ -O0 --coverage -fno-exceptions -fno-inline ....

Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Another solution would be to use `--exclude-throw-branches` if you are running `gcovr`. For example:

```
gcovr --exclude-throw-branches ...
```

This allows you to still throw exceptions in your code but exclude all exception generated branches. More on this in [gcovr FAQ](https://www.gcovr.com/en/stable/faq.html#why-does-c-code-have-so-many-uncovered-branches)