# Function coverage is lesser even with 100% code coverage when objects created in the stack

Tags: c++, gcov, lcov

I'm analyzing my code with gcov. It says my code is 2 functions lesser when objects are created in the stack. But when I do new-delete 100% function coverage is achieved.

Code:

```
class Animal
{
public:
    Animal()
    {
    }
    virtual ~Animal()
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    Animal animal;
}
```

Commands I executed for generate the gcov report.

```
rm -rf Main.g* out.txt a.out coverage;
g++ -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -lgcov -coverage Main.cpp;
./a.out;
lcov --capture --directory . --output-file out.txt;
genhtml out.txt --output-directory coverage;
```

Generated htmls shows my function coverage as 3/4 - 75%.

But once I change my stack object to a heap,

Code:

```
class Animal
{
public:
    Animal()
    {
    }
    virtual ~Animal()
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto animal = new Animal;
    delete animal;
}
```

The my function coverage is 100%.

What are the hidden functions called only when calling "new" and "delete"?

Comment: Have you checked the generated (assembly) code from the first program? Perhaps the compiler simply optimized away the construction and destruction of the `animal` object?

Comment: I can't find the duplicate right now, but usually there is the case where `new` throws an exception which is not covered.

Comment: @nwp but shouldn't the `new Animal` case then be the one without 100% coverage.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46367192/remove-auto-generated-exception-code-from-coverage-report)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a nutshell: g++ creates two destructors for a class

1. One for destructing of the objects.
2. One for destructing of the objects, which were allocated on the heap.

In some scenarios both of them a kept in the object file and in some only the used. In your 75%-coverage-example you use only the first destructor, but both have to be kept in the object file.

---

The link in the answer of @MSalters shows the direction, but it is mostly about multiple constructor/destructor symbols emitted by the g++.

At least to me, it doesn't become directly obvious from this linked answer, what is going on, thus I would like to elaborate .

**First case (100% coverage):**

Let's start with a slightly different definition of the `Animal`-class, one without the `virtual` destructor:

```
class Animal
{
public:
    Animal(){}
    ~Animal(){}
};

int main(){Animal animal;}
```

For this class-definition lcov shows 100% code coverage.

Let's take a look at the symbols in the object file (I built it without gcov for the sake of simplicity):

```
nm main.o
0000000000000000 T main
             U __stack_chk_fail
0000000000000000 W _ZN6AnimalC1Ev
0000000000000000 W _ZN6AnimalC2Ev
0000000000000000 n _ZN6AnimalC5Ev
0000000000000000 W _ZN6AnimalD1Ev
0000000000000000 W _ZN6AnimalD2Ev
0000000000000000 n _ZN6AnimalD5Ev
```

Compiler keeps only those inline functions, which are needed in `main` (functions implemented in a class definition are treated as inline functions, for example there are no copy-constructor or assignment-operator, which are automatically defined by the compiler). I'm not sure what `AnimalX5Ev` are, but for this class there is no difference for `AnimalXC1Ev` (complete object constructor) and `AnimalXC2Ev` (base object constructor) - they have even the same address. As explained in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6921467/5769463), it is some quirks of gcc (but clang has it as well) and byproduct of polymorphism support.

**Second case (75% coverage):**

Let's make the destructor virtual as in our original example, and look at the symbol in the resulting object file:

```
 nm main.o
 0000000000000000 T main
             ...
 0000000000000000 W _ZN6AnimalD0Ev    <----------- NEW
             ...
 0000000000000000 V _ZTV6Animal       <----------- NEW
```

And we see some new symbols: `_ZTV6Animal` is the well known vtable, and `_ZN6AnimalD0Ev` - the so called deleting destructor (read on to see why it is needed). However, in `main` once again only `_ZN6AnimalD1Ev` is used, because nothing changed compared to the first case (compile with `g++ -S main.cpp -o main.s` to see it).

But why on earth is `_ZN6AnimalD0Ev` kept in the object file, if it is not used? Because it is used in the virtual table `_ZTV6Animal` (see the assembly `main.s`):

```
_ZTV6Animal:
   .quad    0
   .quad    _ZTI6Animal
   .quad    _ZN6AnimalD1Ev
   .quad    _ZN6AnimalD0Ev  <---- HERE is the address of the function!
   .weak    _ZTI6Animal
```

But why is this vtable needed? Because every object of a class has a reference to the vtable of the class as soon as there is a virtual method in the class, as can be see in the constructor (still main.s):

```
ZN6AnimalC2Ev:
    ...
    // in register %rdi is the address of the newly created object  
    movl    $_ZTV6Animal+16, (%rdi)     ;write the address of the vtable (why +16?) to the address pointed to by %rdi.
...
```

I must confess, I simplified the assembly a little, but it is easy to see, that the memory layout of a `Animal`-object starts with the address of the virtual table.

This dealocating destructor `_ZN6AnimalD0Ev` is the function for which the coverage is missing - because it is not used in your program.

**Third case (100% coverage again):**

What changes, if we use `new`+`delete`? First we have to know, that destructing an object on the heap is a little bit different than calling a destructor for the object on the stack, because we need to:

1. Destroy the object (it is the same as on the stack i.e. `_ZN6AnimalD1Ev`)
2. Release/free memory which was occupied by the object on the heap.

These two steps are bundled together in the dealocating destructor `_ZN6AnimalD0Ev`, as once again can be seen in the assembly:

```
_ZN6AnimalD0Ev:
    call    _ZN6AnimalD1Ev    ; <---- call "Stack"-destructor
    ....
    call    _ZdlPv            ; free heap memory
    ....
```

Now, in `main` we have to delete the object from the heap, thus `D0`-destructor-version must be called, which calls the `D1`-destructor-version in its turn - which means all functions are used - 100% coverage again.

The last piece of the puzzle, why `D0`-destructor is part of the virtual table? If  `animal` were a `Cat`, how would `main`know which dealocating destructor (the one of `Cat` and not of `Animal`) to call?  By looking at the virtual table of the object pointed to by `animal` and for this the `D0`-destructor is included in the vtable.

However, this all are implementation details of g++, I don't think there is much in the standard enforcing it to be done this way. Nevertheless, clang++ does exactly the same, have to check for MSVS and intel though.

---

PS: Great article about [deleting destructors](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/c-deleting-destructors-and-virtual-operator-delete/).

Answer (score 2):

They're the [allocating constructor and deallocating destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921295/dual-emission-of-constructor-symbols).

This is an implementation detail of `g++`.

Comment: I agree, that this is an implementation detail of g++, but would be surprised if other compilers would handle it differently (at least clang and intel, have not much experience with MSVS).

Comment: And I must confess, that it is not 100% clear what you mean (so at least no allocating constructor (`AnimalC3Ev`) is emitted, as far as I can judge).