# Jenkins Cobertura (with gcov) - what do the coverage statistics mean?

Tags: c++, testing, jenkins, gcov, test-coverage

I'm currently writing unit tests for a `Qt` project. I wanted to use the statistics provided in Jenkins through the **Cobertura** plugin (underneath `gcov` is used to get the stats).

```
:~$ gcov -v
gcov 5.4.0 20160609

:~$ gcc -v
gcc version 5.4.0
```

However after I looked at the table (see below) I was really surprised to see the poor coverage especially of conditionals. For the first one (see *Coverage Breakdown by File*) I thought I was actually done, since the code has only three `if`s(each with a single condition) and my tests covers all (checked this also through debugging just to make sure). So I am really confused what these numbers actually mean and how to interpret them in order to make my unit tests better.

[image]

I've even started thinking that some of the poor results might be due to the use of `Qt` since it's not exactly pure C++ and all "extras" (slots, signals, MOC files etc.) might be something that `gcov` can't handle properly.

Comment: It seems due to exceptions which creates branches in the code is responsible for such scenarios, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42003783/lcov-gcov-branch-coverage-with-c-producing-branches-all-over-the-place/42078101#42078101) is a possible duplicate discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the annotated source listing with displayed red/green coverage markings should help.

The numbers inside the coloured bars are line counts, hence 47/108 means that 47 lines of code out of the 108 lines that are controlled by conditionals, have coverage.

For each conditional you need at least two unit tests: one for each branch.

If there are && or || in the conditions - or anywhere else (eg a logical expression) then each combination must be exercised to achieve 100%.

Also don't forget

```
a = (j == 0) ? c : d;
```

requires (at least) two tests !

Also, if using C++, see [Why gcc 4.1 + gcov reports 100% branch coverage and newer (4.4, 4.6, 4.8) reports 50% for "p = new class;" line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23219614/why-gcc-4-1-gcov-reports-100-branch-coverage-and-newer-4-4-4-6-4-8-report)