# Sonarqube Partially covered tests

Tags: unit-testing, sonarqube

Sonarqube test coverage report says that my c++ statement are only partially covered. Example of a very simplified function containing such statements is as below:

```
std::string test(int num) {
    return "abc";
}
```

My test as follow:

```
TEST(TestFunc, Equal) {
    std::string res = test(0);
    EXPECT_EQ (res, "abc");
}
```

Sonarqube coverage report says that the return stmt is only partially covered by tests (1 of 2 conditions). I am wondering what is other condition that i need to test for?

I also saw the following in the report:

```
Condition to cover: 2
Uncovered Condition: 1
Condition Coverage: 50%
```

It seems like i need a test to cover the other condition but i cant figure out what that is.

Answer (score 1):

After more research, this is not a Sonarqube problem. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23219614/why-gcc-4-1-gcov-reports-100-branch-coverage-and-newer-4-4-4-6-4-8-report) (and the way around it) most likely explain the root cause of my problem.

Related post: [LCOV/GCOV branch coverage with C++ producing branches all over the place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42003783/lcov-gcov-branch-coverage-with-c-producing-branches-all-over-the-place)